# Kafka Connect to Read files from a directory

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I'm moving the streaming app from flume to kafka. So needed help since I'm new to kafka.

I've a windows machine on which CSV Files are continously being generated by IOT sensors at a particular location say D:/Folder. I want to transfer it to a hadoop cluster.

There are millions of small files being generated daily in the folder. And i want to spool the folder with kafka for any new files. 
Which Kafka connect should I use to spool the directory for new files.
I read about kafka connect fileStream but I think it only works with 1 file.

Comment: https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Comment: Why can't you use Flume spooldir?

Comment: there are many consumers in my case reading from the same source hence we went ahead with a publish subscribe model which kafka provides

Comment: Consumers don't care that you have a spooldir, they just want data in Kafka. Flume can send data from a directory to Kafka... That's my point

Comment: The alternative would be FluentD or Beats

Comment: This is an old question but maybe this new project can help people looking for such connector  : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse

Answer (score 1):

Use Kafka-connect-spooldir. It supports reading all csv files within a folder

https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.